# Yii2 Linking two models not working when saving user-submitted data from form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, yii2

I have two models: one for "Experts" (based on a database table of their contact details), and one for "Expertise" (such as 'PHP', 'JavaScript', 'Java', ..., also in database table). Since an expert can have more than one expertise, and an expertise can be held by several experts, this is a many-to-many relationship that is defined in the model classes, see below. The relationship should be stored in a junction table.

```
// in models/RcccExperts.php

class RcccExperts extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
   ...

   public function getRcccExpertise() 
   {
      return $this->hasMany(RcccExpertise::className(), ['id' => 'expertise_id'])
        ->viaTable('rccc_experts_expertise', ['expert_id' => 'id']);
   }
}


// in models/RcccExpertise.php

class RcccExpertise extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    ...

    public function getRcccExperts() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RcccExperts::className(), ['id' => 'expert_id'])
          ->viaTable('rccc_experts_expertise', ['expertise_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

The user can add a new entry to the experts database via a form that contains data from both models. The user can assign expertise to the expert via a multiple select form field (implemented with select2 tags), where s/he can select from existing expertise (already in the database) or add new expertise tags.

When I try to link the two models to populate the junction table (that contains the expert IDs and expertise IDs), I get the following error message:

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Call to a member function getIsNewRecord() on array
in /Users/Sites/Yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php at line 1248
```

I'm aware that when linking two models using `->viaTable`, both models mustn't be newly created. In my case, the Expert model has just been saved and has a primary key id; I'm retrieving the Expertise ids that were selected for the Expert from the database.

Whichever way I try to link the two models, the problem seems to be that the Expertise is not recognized as an existing model, but as an `array()`.

What am I doing wrong?!

More details on the error below:

```
 * This parameter is only meaningful for a relationship involving a junction table
 * (i.e., a relation set with [[ActiveRelationTrait::via()]] or [[ActiveQuery::viaTable()]].)
 * @throws InvalidCallException if the method is unable to link two models.
 */
public function link($name, $model, $extraColumns = [])
{
    $relation = $this->getRelation($name);

    if ($relation->via !== null) {
        if ($this->getIsNewRecord() || $model->getIsNewRecord()) {
            throw new InvalidCallException('Unable to link models: the models being linked cannot be newly created.');
        }
        if (is_array($relation->via)) {
            /* @var $viaRelation ActiveQuery */
            list($viaName, $viaRelation) = $relation->via;
            $viaClass = $viaRelation->modelClass;
            // unset $viaName so that it can be reloaded to reflect the change
            unset($this->_related[$viaName]);
        } else {
...
```

After the form to create a new expert has been submitted, this is the Controller code to execute:

```
// in controllers/ExpertsController.php
/**
 * ExpertsController implements the CRUD actions for RcccExperts model.
 */
class ExpertsController extends Controller
{
 ...

 public function actionCreate()
 {
    $model = new RcccExperts();
    $expertise = new RcccExpertise();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $expertise->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        if ($model->validate() && $expertise->validate()) {

            if ($model->save()) {

                // Once the Expert's model data has been saved
                // Go ahead and process the Expertise ids form the multiple select form field:
                // First save the expertise (coming from a multiple select form field where the user can
                // select existing expertise tags or add new ones) to the database

                $array = $expertise->expertise; 
                $expertise_ids = array();

                foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
                    $exp = new RcccExpertise(); 

                    // Check that the expertise does not exist yet
                    $check1 = $expertise->find()->where(['id' => $value])->one();  
                    $check2 = $expertise->find()->where(['expertise' => $value])->one();

                    if ($check1 == null && $check2 == null) {
                        $exp->expertise = $value;

                        // Save new expertise 
                        $exp->save();
                        $result = $expertise->find()->select('id')->where(['expertise' => $value])->one(); 
                        $expertise_ids[] = $result->id;
                    }
                    else $expertise_ids[] = $value;

                }
                $expertise->id = $expertise_ids;

                // Put the new expertise IDs in a model instance
                $expertises = RcccExpertise::find()->where(['id' => $expertise->id])->all();

                // Link expert model with expertise model
                // to populate the junction table
                $model->link('rcccExpertise', $expertises);
            }
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } 
    }
    else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'expertise' => $expertise,
            'languages' => $languages,
            'attachments' => $attachments
        ]);
    }
}
```

The MySQL tables holding this information look like this:

```
`CREATE TABLE `rccc_experts` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `skype` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `rccc_experts`ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `rccc_experts` MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE `rccc_expertise` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `expertise` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `rccc_expertise` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `rccc_expertise` MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE `rccc_experts_expertise` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `expert_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `expertise_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `rccc_experts_expertise` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `rccc_experts_expertise` MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Relation `hasMany` returns array of objects. To make it work, you have to loop over this array, like:

```
foreach ($model->rcccExperts as $expert) {
         // do your stuff here on $expert variable
}
```

Comment: That almost solved it! $model is just an object, but I'm getting $expertises in an array of objects, so by going over $expertises I can link each $expertise object to the expert model like this: `foreach ($expertises as $expertise) {
    $model->link('rcccExpertise', $expertise);
}` Thank you so much for your help!